# How to retrieve active network information in android

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an android application.For one of the feature, I need the active network information(i.e. whether it's connected with  Wi-Fi or mobile data). I got this piece of code from the internet.

`NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class).getActiveNetworkInfo();`

But this API is deprecated and I don't want to use any deprecated API.

After some more googling, I found that we should use `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` instead. But I am not able to get an example of it. How can I use this?. Please help me if anyone having an idea about using `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this function in Kotlin

```
fun networkConnection(): Boolean {
        var networkAvailable = false

        val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val network: Network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork!!
        val networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)!!

        if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
            networkAvailable = true
        } else if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            networkAvailable = true
        } else if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)) {
            networkAvailable = true
        }

        return networkAvailable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
private void registerNetworkCallback(Context context) {
  final ConnectivityManager manager =
      (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  manager.registerNetworkCallback(
      new NetworkRequest.Builder()
          .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
          .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)
          .build(),
      new NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
         /** here to get the available info
         this ternary operation is not quite true, because non-metered 
         doesn't yet mean, that it's wifi
         nevertheless, for simplicity let's assume that's true
         */

     Log.i("vvv", "connected to " + (manager.isActiveNetworkMetered() ? "LTE" : "WIFI"));
        }
       @Override
        public void onCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, 
         NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities){
             /**here to get the change network info
              Value is TRANSPORT_CELLULAR, TRANSPORT_WIFI, 
              TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH, TRANSPORT_ETHERNET, TRANSPORT_VPN
             */
            if(networkCapabilities.hasTransport("type")){
            }
         }
      });
}
```

Comment: I hope this is not targeting mobile connection.

Comment: in onAvailable method, how can I differentiate between wifi and mobile connection?

Comment: you can use `manager.isActiveNetworkMetered() ? "LTE" : "WIFI"` to check. true is avoid large network data, that means LTE

Answer (score 0):

```
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);


 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void getActiveNet() {
        Network currentNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Note that "active network" is synonymous in android with "default network".

[ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo())

> Returns details about the currently active default data network...

[ConnectivityManager#registerDefaultNetworkCallback(NetworkCallback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerDefaultNetworkCallback(android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback))

> Registers to receive notifications about changes in the application's
> default network...

Therefore using `ConnectivityManager#registerDefaultNetworkCallback(NetworkCallback)` you can listen for default (aka "active") network changes. Unfortunately, this only returns the `Network` object which does not have information regarding transport (Wi-Fi vs Cellular) in which case you'll need to make an additional call to [ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities(Network)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities(android.net.Network)) to get that info.

Here is an example:

```
final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final NetworkCallback networkCallback = new NetworkCallback() {
  @Override
  void onAvailable(Network network) {
      // Triggers when a default network is available.
      NetworkCapabilities nc = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
      boolean isWifi = nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
      boolean isCellular = nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities. TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
  }
};

connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
```